# How to auto increment release versioning of Javascrpt build in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: javascript, node.js, jenkins

I have a react app that I have deployed using the Jenkins pipeline.

Now I want to implement an increment release version in the Jenkins pipeline (Jenkinsfile).

Using a Java application, the code below works well in the Jenkins pipeline(Jenkinsfile). How do I implement a similar thing with a React, Nodejs, and Javascript application?

```
stages {
    stage('increment version') {
        steps {
            script {
                echo 'incrementing app version...'
                sh 'mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set \
                    -DnewVersion=\\\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\\\${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.\\\${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion} \
                    versions:commit'
                def matcher = readFile('pom.xml') =~ '<version>(.+)</version>'
                def version = matcher[0][1]
                env.IMAGE_NAME = "$version-$BUILD_NUMBER"
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To increment a release version for any nodeJS app you can use:
`npm version patch`
for more details check npm-version documentation [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-version)

in my jenkins file am using the following:

```
    sh '''
        git fetch
        git checkout $BRANCH_NAME
        CURRENT_VERSION=$(node -p "require('./package.json').version")
        npm version patch --git-tag-version false
        UPDATED_VERSION=$(node -p "require('./package.json').version")
        git add package.json
        [ -f ./package-lock.json ] && git add package-lock.json
        git commit -m "Updating service version from $CURRENT_VERSION to $UPDATED_VERSION"
        '''
```

i set `--git-tag-version` to false cause the default is true.

Comment: Hi @DanTe, thank you for the information. From git add package.json
        [ -f ./package-lock.json ] && git add package-lock.json
        git commit -m "Updating service version from $CURRENT_VERSION to $UPDATED_VERSION"

I assume you are updating the package.json with the new version.

Comment: Hi @DanTe, I have this error. Do I have to import anything?

org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 3: unexpected token: require('./package.json').version @ line 3, column 31.
       CURRENT_VERSION=$(node -p "require('./package.json').version")
                                 ^

1 error

 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:309)

Comment: Hi @EmmanuelOga, am using `CURRENT_VERSION` and `UPDATED_VERSION` variables in my commit message only. and regarding to the error message make sure to use multiple line script syntax, it's mostly a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks for the hands up. It is working now